# Can't recommend close questions in LQP if previously flagged

Tags: bug, review, flags, low-quality-posts

My personal habit of browsing SE is:

- View the first page, and flag some questions
- Irrelevant: Answer questions that I can
- Clear the review queue

Now notice the 1st and 3rd things. I flag OT questions before doing review works, and some of them appear like this:

[image]

I don't think hitting "Looks OK" will affect the result of the review, because I think my previous flag should kick the same post into CV queue (and 3K people will close it). Am I right?

Comment: Solution: hit [Skip]. It *would* be nice if these were filtered out upfront.

Comment: @Glorfindel See edit.

Comment: *I want badges for LQP.* that's not why you should be reviewing.

Comment: @Glorfindel I know that's not the **primary** purpose, but it should be OK being a **secondary** purpose.

Comment: Your previous flag *will* kick the post into CV, yes, but theoretically the extra flags/votes gained by higher visibility in LQP will tend to sort the post higher in CV as well, so Looks OK is wrong.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Given the traffic on Android.SE, everyone will complete the whole queue when visiting, so as a result the question will be closed ASAP.

Comment: On Android, maybe. On other sites, no.